# ClassCastException while Flink run : cannot assign instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap to field org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.JobVertex.results

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Error when run Flink job:

```
ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap to field org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.JobVertex.results of type java.util.ArrayList in instance of org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.InputOutputFormatVertex
```

Below is the source code

```java
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

        env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(params);

        DataSet<String> text = env.readTextFile(params.get("input"));

        DataSet<String> filtered = text.filter(new FilterFunction<String>()

        {
            public boolean filter(String value)
            {
                return value.startsWith("N");
            }
        });
        DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> tokenized = filtered.map(new Tokenizer());

        DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts = tokenized.groupBy(new int[] { 0 }).sum(1);
        if (params.has("output"))
        {
            counts.writeAsText(params.get("output"));

            env.execute("WordCount Example");
        }
    }

    public static final class Tokenizer
            implements MapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>
    {
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> map(String value)
        {
            return new Tuple2(value, Integer.valueOf(1));
        }
    }
```

Error:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37bZf.png)

Comment: Perhaps this is a version mismatch. What version of Flink is the cluster running, and what does the pom file look like?

Comment: Flink cluster version is 1.17.0 and POM also has all lastest version @DavidAnderson

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.0</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right David Anderson, It was a version mismatch on my local machine,
I have fixed this by upgrading my local Flink cluster version to latest version.